# Duplicate data after passing model to my list

Tags: android, list

I'm getting data from api in json , when i get the data and pass it to the model using setters , the data is not duplicated as i checked on logcat , but as soon as i add it to the list , it gets duplicated , i check api response and model again and again and there is no duplicate , my list gets duplicate values after passing the model

This is my code

```
 private void ShowData() {

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));

        String api_key = "https://www.qpisite.com/api/v1/json/1/eventspastleague.php?id=4328&s=1920";

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, api_key, null, 
            response -> {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("events");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    final String date = jsonObject.getString("dateEvent");
                    final String hometeam = jsonObject.getString("strHomeTeam");
                    final String awayteam = jsonObject.getString("strAwayTeam");
                    final String homescore = 
                    jsonObject.getString("intHomeScore");
                    final String awayscore = 
                    jsonObject.getString("intAwayScore");
                    final String homeid = jsonObject.getString("idHomeTeam");
                    final String awayid = jsonObject.getString("idAwayTeam");
                    final String eventid = jsonObject.getString("idEvent");
                    final String time = jsonObject.getString("strTime");
                    final int myround = jsonObject.getInt("intRound");

                     Model model = new Model();
                     model.setDate(date);
                     model.setAwaylogo(awaylogo);
                     model.setHometeam(hometeam);
                     model.setAwayteam(awayteam);
                     model.setStadium(stadium);
                     model.setHomelogo(homelogo);
                     model.setHomescore(homescore);
                    model.setAwayscore(awayscore);
                    model.setRound(myround);
                    model.setTime(mytime);
                    model.setEventid(eventid);
                    model.setDetails("Details");

                    modelList.add(model); // this is where i have duplicate data

                 ///// using hashmap for grouping and i actually have two view 
                 ///   holders 
                 LinkedHashMap<String, List<Model>> groupedHashMap = 
                  groupDataIntoHashMap(modelList);

                   for (String date1 : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
                   MyDateItem dateItem = new MyDateItem();
                  dateItem.setDate(date1);
                  consolidatedList.add(dateItem);

                for (Model pojoOfJsonArray : groupedHashMap.get(date1)) {
                MyGeneralItem generalItem = new MyGeneralItem();
               generalItem.setModel(pojoOfJsonArray);
               consolidatedList.add(generalItem);
             }                                           


              ssadapter = new Ssadapter(consolidatedList, getContext());
              recyclerView.setAdapter(ssadapter);


                          }

                         }

                    } catch (
                   JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                          }
                   }, error -> {

                  });
             requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest2);...
```

Comment: Where did you call the above API? Are you calling the API inside the adapter function?

Comment: No im calling it in a void method  in fragment, because later i check if internet is connected i pass the method else if offline i pass my saved data , i edited the code above to be clearer